# Cheap cycling shoes feel 'sloppy' when pulling up

Tags: shoes

I recently bought some cheap ($60) mountain bike shoes. It changed my riding style, and I'm really 'pedaling in a circle' now.

I have a complaint though... when I sprint and put a lot of force into the other-than-down parts of the stroke, my foot moves around a lot. It doesn't feel efficient, and is rather annoying.

If I tighten the straps enough that this doesn't happen, it really constricts my feet and isn't comfortable.

[image]

I haven't found it useful to tighten the ratchet before sprinting/attacking. I would rather have the ratchet over my toes, as that's where most of the movement is.

So... is this normal for cycling (mountain) shoes? If not, is it because mine are cheap or do I just have a bad fit?

Comment: Basically, what you describe would be due to a too-soft sole, laces not tight enough, or simply a poor fit.  Though I suppose it could also be due to having "uppers" that are too stretchy.

Comment: This could do with a picture of the fastening arrangement, as  you may have some options that aren't immediately apparent. For example there are ways to thread laces to allow different tensions in different zones. You may also get some benefit from the least compressible thick insole you can find/make.

Comment: @ChrisH Mine have two velcro straps and a ratchet

Comment: Have you checked for clear wear? Sometimes this can cause the feeling of sloppiness

Comment: Another thing you might have is the cleats not being fully attached or worn. If you don't have recessed cleats, walking a little bit can ruin them.

Comment: Where exactly those straps are, how they're attached, and whether there are any other eyelets/tabs that could be used for an extra fastening, are some of the things I was wondering about.

Comment: @Batman I've got recessed spd cleats and they're almost new.

Comment: @ChrisH Added pic

Comment: In my experience Shimano SPD (even when new) have quite some play in all directions.

Comment: @Michael I can make the 'slop' I'm talking about go away by over-tightening my shoes, so I don't think it's the pedal/cleat's fault

Comment: @BSOrider: Oh, okay. Then I guess it’s really a problem with your shoes or feet? The only advice I can think of is that I usually tighten the ratchets/straps during riding because somehow the feet always “settle down” during the first few minutes and are much more loose then.

Comment: I'm guessing the shoes are too large.

Comment: IMO you're right and the ratchet is too high to be much use. Everything relies on the lower velcro, and that can only do so much. A further fastening forward of that velcro would help but there's no obvious way to attach it. It looks like either they don't fit well enough at all, or maybe you need to pack out the toe end of the shoe a bit (if, like me, your feet are long but not wide).

Comment: Some undersole inserts might be of assistance for packing up the areas where you get movement.  As a test, try adding chunks of cardboard layered up.  Leave your toes free - you don't want the end of the shoe tight around your toes.

Comment: I wonder if your problem is that your cleats are set too far forward.  If they are too far forward (and it varies slightly from one pedal to the next) it will make the shoe feel "sloppy"

Comment: @DanielRHicks They were too far forward, and I had to cut extensions in the slots to allow me to get the cleat underneath the ball of my foot. I have wide feet, so I generally get a size larger than I would otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Visually it looks like a velcro issue to me.
Basically, velcro straps are fine to maintain regular together because of the relatively low mechanical constraint on them.

When riding a bike however, the vertical constrains due to the pedal-locking are way more important. This causes your straps to extend slightly (because velcro straps are a based on a fabric ribbon and when you stretch a fabric ribbon it extends) thus causing a lack of adherence because the little hooks unhooks themselves. This is why after a while your strapping seems to get looser, it's because it actually get looser.

Unfortunately there is little to do against that with your shoes.

This problem is pretty common and explains why in higher end shoes you got complicated hybrid strap+lacing systems in order to balance the benefits of each.

So ideally for bugdet I would say : switch to full lacing shoes, it's a pain to put on and off but it stays in place pretty good.

The other technical solution to the problem is to buy some fiberglass reinforced strapped shoes. It's more expensive, I myself have an old pair of Carnac Quartz (it's composed with four fiberglass straps instead of three) that where somewhat expensive at launch (around 200dollars) but with it you can hammer the pedal, it won't budge at all because of the fiberglass which prevent the velcro to expand.